# Entity framework Invalid Column name after add set in custom attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi everyone I got a problem with a relationship in Entity Framework after I added a set on propriety PadreNombre or MadreNombre that made it with a relationship

```
    [Required]
    public long PadreId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long MadreId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MadreId")]
    public Padres Madre { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PadreId")]
    public Padres Padre { get; set; }

    public string PadreNombre
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Padre != null)
            {
                return this.Padre.Nombres + ' ' + this.Padre.ApellidoPaterno + ' ' + this.ApellidoMaterno;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        set
        {
        }

    }

    public string MadreNombre
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Madre != null)
            {
                return this.Madre.Nombres + ' ' + this.Madre.ApellidoPaterno + ' ' + this.Madre.ApellidoMaterno;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        set
        {
        }
    }
```

That some part of my class model, it was working perfectly until I added the method "set", before I don't need it but now that I want to implement throw me a SqlException with "Invalid name 'MadreNombre', invalid name 'PadreNombre' ",
someone have had a similar problem??

Comment: as @Sergey mentioned, add NotMapped attribute, because you won't store PadreNombre and MadreNombre values in the database, these properties will only return values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [NotMapped] attribute:

```
[NotMapped] 
public string PadreNombre
{
..... your code
}

[NotMapped] 
public string MadreNombre
{
..... your code
}
```

Comment: Ok now its working thanks, but if a want create an instance and set PadreNombre the new object is empty in PadreNombre even if a set

Comment: var students = _context.Students.ToList();

                students = students.Select(x => new Alumno
                    { 
                     Curp = x.Curp, 
                     Nombres = x.Nombres, 
                     ApellidoPaterno = x.ApellidoPaterno, 
                     ApellidoMaterno = x.ApellidoMaterno, 
                     PadreNombre = x.PadreNombre,
                     MadreNombre = x.MadreNombre 
                }).ToList();
I need something like this but with NotMapped the PadreNombre in my new object is empty, is possible do something like I want?

Comment: Use var students = _context.Students. Inlclude(=>i.Padre). Include( =>i.Madre)ToList(); After this you can use unmapped properties.

Comment: Yes but when I tried  new Alumno
                    { 
                     Curp = x.Curp, 
                     Nombres = x.Nombres, 
                     ApellidoPaterno = x.ApellidoPaterno, 
                     ApellidoMaterno = x.ApellidoMaterno, 
                     PadreNombre = "asd",
                     MadreNombre = "dsa" 
                }
 MadreNombre and PadreNombre is null :(

Comment: Yes, it will be since you don't have a setter. How computer knows what is Nombres ApellidoPaterno  and ApellidoMaterno in "asd"? To make it possible Instead of  get , you have to use  string PadreNombre {get; set; } as an extra column in your Student db table, but if you want to do this it is better to  add  a column  PadreNombre  to your Padre db table.

Comment: Or use new Alumno { ....,  PadreNombre = new PadreNombre {  Nombres =..., ApellidoPaterno = ..., ApellidoMaterno =... }  , ....}

Comment: Sorry forgive my spanish use new Alumno { ...., Padre= new Padre { Nombres =..., ApellidoPaterno = ..., ApellidoMaterno =... } , ....}

Answer (score 2):

Properties without a setter are readonly properties. EF will automatically ignore them. By adding a setter to the properties, you made them read/write so EF will now try to map them to a column in the database. Since the column probably don't exist, the context throws an exception.

- If you want to persist the properties values in the database, you need to add the appropriate column in the database.
- If you don't want the data to persist in the database, add the `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]` attribute to the property.

Comment: NotMapped  propery  with a geter is not  ReadOnly proper of EF. Thesse are different kind of properties for EF.

Comment: @Sergey sorry, i don't understand you comment. I'm not talking about ReadOnlyAttribute. A "readonly property" is a way to describe a property that does not have a setter.

Comment: By default, EF model builder only tries to bind public properties with both getter and setter. When your property only had a getter, EF would ignore it. You added a setter to the property, and now EF will look for a column in the database and throw an error.

Comment: I mean  EF load readonly column in the class instance but even doesn't try to save it. For example it maybe calculated column that exist in Db table. It will be always read by select query but never save. This column usually calculates and updates by DB triger. Notmapped property doesn't have any column in DB and  EF completely ignores this property when EF works with DB.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps your use case requires features that are only available with fluent API ? Not everything is possible with attributes.